How can I remove the plastic covers from my window blind mounting brackets?
I got these roller blinds from B&M and instructions are not at helpful. It says that you can slide the plastic on but now idea how? I need to screw them to the wall but without taking off plastic cover it is impossible.




try unclipping the wedge shaped tabs ... they are on right in the picture

Slide a flat screwdriver in at the red arrow and lift the metal tab enough that it clears the plastic tabs circled in blue.
The metal & plastic pieces should then slide apart


thanks, I thought it will break. I took out one for now, but it seem a little bend (the metal thing), it was hard to pull it out though really hard
